# What are the current security issues S-BGP has?

Tags: bgp, asymmetric-routing

The question is explained in full in the title. I wish to know what the security issues are when deploying S-BGP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Aside from security, it is extremely complex, slowing updates and convergence.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S-BGP is still a draft at IETF: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-clynn-s-bgp-protocol-01. So I think that you will have to deal with unstable implementations. It is more likely an operational issue than a security one.